# Not able to view web page in webview on Android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, flutterwebviewplugin

I am trying to run the [WebView Sample](https://github.com/efortuna/wiki_browser) of `Flutter` in `android emulator` which is provided by `Android studio` itself. Now the problem I am facing is while I am running the sample I am not able to view the web page in `WebView` itself.
 When the app runs for the first time it asks me to open the `initialUrl` into either into the `chrome` or `web browser` see below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

However, when I run the same sample in my mobile device it works fine and I can see the web page insdie `WebView`

[image]

***Code***

```
class _WikipediaExplorerState extends State<WikipediaExplorer> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  final Set<String> _favorites = Set<String>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Wikipedia Explorer'),
        // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
        actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
          Menu(_controller.future, () => _favorites),
        ],
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraken',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _bookmarkButton(),
    );
  }

  _bookmarkButton() {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _controller.future,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
        if (controller.hasData) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              var url = await controller.data.currentUrl();
              _favorites.add(url);
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text('Saved $url for later reading.')),
              );
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          );
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code snippet

Comment: @akshaybhange i have already share the git link of flutter example , i have not modified anything , it is just a ready example i run

Comment: I think this problem from emulator. Do you try genymotion emulator for stable results.

Comment: Do you have any fix for this simulator ? As genymotion is too heavy to use on system

Comment: May you can try reinstall emulator

Comment: have you tried running it on a real device ? what is the result ?

Comment: @henok I have already shared in my question that I am able to view it on mobile device with screenshot

Comment: Try updating the webview_flutter to the latest version(as if now webview_flutter: ^0.3.13 ) on your pubspec.yaml file.